# `hardhat-deploy` giving zero address owner instead of deployer!

Tags: hardhat-deploy

**Hi Devs**

*I'm in the middle of a professional project & facing a small issue. Your help will sincerely appreciated*

I deployed the upgradeable contract below using `UpgradeableBeacon` and `hardhat-deploy`. The deployment is fine to some extend, can read methods/functions from contract except for two essential functions 1- `owner` & 2- `implementation` address.

I modified `upgradeableBeacon` constructor to initilaize function so `Factory` can inherit it. nothing major.

*what I did to troubleshot this problem:*

I tried using `getContractAt` using deployments, contract abi, & address. `getContractAt` using contract name and deployer address. & using `getContract`. same results everytime

**UpgradeableBeacon Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/IBeacon.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/AddressUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol';

contract UpgradeableBeacon is Initializable, IBeacon, OwnableUpgradeable {
    address private _implementation;

    event Upgraded(address indexed implementation);

    function __UpgradeableBeacon_init(address implementation_) public virtual onlyInitializing{
        __Ownable_init();
        _setImplementation(implementation_);
    }

    function implementation() public view virtual override returns (address) {
        return _implementation;
    }

    function upgradeTo(address newImplementation) public virtual onlyOwner {
        _setImplementation(newImplementation);
        emit Upgraded(newImplementation);
    }

    function _setImplementation(address newImplementation) private {
        require(AddressUpgradeable.isContract(newImplementation), "UpgradeableBeacon: implementation is not a contract");
        _implementation = newImplementation;
    }
}
```

**Factory Contract**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/BeaconProxy.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol';
import './interfaces/IFactory.sol';
import './interfaces/IDTokenInterface.sol';
import './proxy/UpgradeableBeacon.sol';



contract Factory is Initializable, IRealtyFactory,PausableUpgradeable, UpgradeableBeacon {


  IDTokenInterface private ID;


  function __Factory_init(address idContract, address impl) public virtual initializer {
    __Pausable_init();
    __UpgradeableBeacon_init(impl);

    ID = IDTokenInterface(idContract);
  }
}
```

**Deployment Script using hardhat-deploy**

```
const { ethers, network } = require('hardhat')

module.exports = async({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const { deploy, log, get } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    // console.log({namedAccounts: await getNamedAccounts()})

    const networkName = network.name
    const idToken = await get('IDToken')
    // console.log(`IDToken Contract address is ${idToken.address}`)

    const implementation = await deploy('BitRealty', {
        contract: 'BitRealty',
        args:[],
        log: true,
        from: deployer,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })

    const deployedImp = await ethers.getContractAt('BitRealty', implementation.address)


    const factory = await deploy('Factory', {
        contract: 'Factory',
        from: deployer,
        args:[],
        log: true,
        execute: {
            methodName: '__Factory_init',
            args:[idToken.address, implementation.address]
        },
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })
    const tryFactory = await deployments.get('Factory')
    const deployedFactory = await ethers.getContractAt(tryFactory.abi, tryFactory.address)

    console.log(`Deployed Implementation Address:  ${implementation.address}`)
    console.log(`Deployed Factory Address:  ${factory.address}`)
    console.log(`Deployer: ${deployer}`)
    console.log(`Factory Owner from Factory:  ${await deployedFactory.owner()}`)
    console.log(`Implementation Address from Factory:  ${await deployedFactory.implementation()}`)
    console.log(`Is Factory Paused:  ${await deployedFactory.isPaused()}`)

}
module.exports.tags = ['all']
```

And Finally this is the output of console.log reading factory functions:
Error 1: owner should deployer but its address zero
Error2: implementation address is address zero

```
deploying "BitRealty" (tx: 0x0997482ff562049e8200a04d77438f96372d63b5d764caa0b0e57086b4ecb6a8)...: deployed at 0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9 with 2257315 gas
deploying "Factory" (tx: 0xd2e12dfe86fe9d61eb5bc3f3b0ff5f26671c185acfc9c49044fe7f2ddbe398f0)...: deployed at 0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707 with 2675360 gas
Deployed Implementation Address:  0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9
Deployed Factory Address:  0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707
Deployer: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
Factory Owner from Factory:  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Implementation Address from Factory:  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Is Factory Paused:  false
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Factory Contract.sol` file the initialisation function of the factory is called `__Factory_init` where as when deploying the contract you are calling the `__RealtyFactory_init`. Do you see it? 
The line where you deploy the factory:

```
const factory = await deploy('Factory', {
        contract: 'Factory',
        from: deployer,
        args:[],
        log: true,
        execute: {
            methodName: '__RealtyFactory_init',
            args:[idToken.address, implementation.address]
        },
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })
```

Should be as follows:

```
const factory = await deploy('Factory', {
        contract: 'Factory',
        from: deployer,
        args:[],
        log: true,
        execute: {
            methodName: '__Factory_init',
            args:[idToken.address, implementation.address]
        },
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Hristo for your response, Originally the contract name is `RealtyFactory` but I changed here in the question as the project is really big, I will correct it here. but if you look at the console log you will see I can read contract functions except for 2 mentioned above!!